# Magento 2 Installation Error

Tags: magento2, php, installation, setup

I've installing **Magento 2** on my server but i've got below message error :

```
{{$state.current.noMenu ? $state.current.title : titles[$state.current.type]}}
```

See screenshot :[image]

Any Solution please?

Comment: Which browser and magento 2 version you are using ?

Comment: I’ve using Firefox browser and Magento 2.1.8

Comment: Try downloading fresh step up again.

Comment: I just did but it's not working :)

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to Angular JS not rendering on the page as the setup installer is still using it.

I suggest you to **update your PHP** and environment and then try another browser. The issue is a little tedious to fix.

Comment: On Mac, i've using FireFox browser but still on chrome working without any issue.